# How to run websocket and client on different ports

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ports

I have the following client ( serves the chat interface ) and a websocket, which are connected by the http. Http at the moment runs on the port 8080. So I would like to run the client on one port and the websocket on another, but if I disconnect them by http and of course the websocket doesn´t work on the client.

So is there a way to run them on different ports but still have them connected by the http ?

server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs')
var port = 8080;

/************************************************ */
if (process.argv.indexOf('--port') >= 0) {
    port = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('--port') + 1]
}

/************************************************ **/
var sIndexHtmlTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index1.html', 'utf8');

/************************************************ ***/
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

/************************************************ ***/

http.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening on *' + port);
});
```

Comment: You can change your SocketIO Server port to 3000 and open inbound port 3000 on your Server. What's problems with you, bro?

Comment: I want to run the app on a different port and the websocket on an other.